# Arduino - Play MP3 From SD Card

Tags: arduino

I have an SD Card Shield from seeed studio attached to my Arduino Uno board. I also have an SD card with a siren .MP3 file in it. I want my Arduino board to play the MP3 file but I am not sure how to get it to do that. I have a speaker connected as well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the Arduino is not able to decode MP3's. As an alternative you could convert the MP3 to the less cpu intensive WAVe file format then use [Adafruit's Wave library](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-wave-shield-audio-shield-for-arduino) to play the file out a pin.

Or you can use the [VS1053 Co-Processor Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10628) to play the MP3 file.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino Uno does not have enough power to play MP3s in software. You will need to get a separate hardware MP3 decoder and instruct it to play them instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Library that will play WAV files. It can be found at https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm